# HTML setting image for background

Tags: html

Hello I'm a beginner in HTML and I wanna ask if I can set an imege like this one http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/water_drops_on_glass-wide.jpg HTML for the background. Please help!

Comment: Hi, please remember to always Google first. We won't be able to tell you anything that `HTML set background` doesn't tell you already. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=HTML+setting+image+for+background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this entry to your stylesheet, or insert this in the  section of your HTML:

```
   <style>
    body {
        background-image:url('http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/water_drops_on_glass-wide.jpg');
}
    </style>
```

Comment: Questions like this one shouldn't even be answered IMO. It's just encouraging them to ask more of them.